# java object cannot be cast from different package sources

Tags: java, sockets, casting

I have two different package "mas.back.task.Checker" and "mas.front.task.Checker", which "Checker" is the class, I implemented sending the class from client socket to server socket with bytebuffer's serialization, I successfully serialized but when converting from "mas.front.task.Checker" to "mas.back.task.Checker", it does not work and error messages here:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: mas.front.task.Checker cannot be cast to mas.back.task.Checker
```

The code sending the class via client socket to server socket here:

```
public static final Object convertByteToObject(byte[] bytes) {
    ObjectInput in;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        return in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Converter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

public static final byte[] convertObjectToByte(Object object) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(object);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Converter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I confirmed that all fields in the class of Checker are same, also I tried "Checker checker = new Checker()", but when "checker = (Checker) object", the error showed as above messages, so how can I fix this issues?

Remark:

```
public class Checker implements Serializable {
    public String JobID;
    public String JobUserID;
    public int JobInterval;
    public String JobStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two `Checker` classes belong to different packages, they are different.  It doesn't matter that you made sure that they are identical in terms of the fields or even methods defined in the class - they have different package hierarchies and are therefore not the same. **You can easily reproduce this problem without serializing or de-serializing the instances.**  Just try to declare a variable of type `Checker` from one package, and casting it into the other.

Why don't you extract `Checker` into a common package higher up in your package hierarchy that can be imported lower in `front.task` and `back.task`?

Comment: The reason is to send the class via TCP/IP socket by serializing or de-serializing, the frontend client is mas.front.task.XXX and the backend is mas.back.task.XXX for the class, do you have any suggestion on above?

Comment: And the second reason is I need to send not only the type of Checker but also other type of.

Comment: Did you write the Checker classes?

Comment: Yes, I sured, because I have frontend and backend server, they are not same package path, of course....

Comment: @AndyChan To put Amir's suggestion another way, you should put `Checker` in a separate library project that is used by your front and back end projects.  Perhaps you could call it `mas.common.task.Checker`.

Comment: OK, If only choice, I will use it.